# Map.Map vs function

Tags: haskell, profiling

why is using data constructors and a function slower than using Strings and a Map in this situation?

Edit: Please note my second comment to Rotsor's answer, it explains why i accepted nulvinges answer.

Runs slowly:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.List as List

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ conspire fabFive fabFive

-- here i actually have 80 constructors
data Eris = Hera | Athene | Aphrodite | Paris | Helene
            deriving (Ord, Eq, Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)

fabFive = [minBound..maxBound] :: [Eris]

conspire :: [Eris] -> [Eris] -> [Eris]
conspire [Hera]   [Hera]   = [Hera, Athene]
...
conspire [Hera]   [Helene] = [Athene, Aphrodite, Paris]
...
conspire [Helene] [Helene] = [Hera]

conspire [a] (b:bs) =
    List.union (conspire [a] [b]) (conspire [a] bs)
conspire (a:as) ls =
    List.union (conspire [a] ls) (conspire as ls)
```

Runs faster:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    print $ conspire (Set.fromList fabFive) (Set.fromList fabFive)

fabFive = [ Hera, Athene, Aphrodite, Paris, Helene ]

conspire :: Set.Set String -> Set.Set String -> Set.Set String
conspire set1 set2 = Set.fold Set.union Set.empty $ Set.map
    (\x -> Set.fold Set.union Set.empty $ Set.map
        (\y -> conspiracy Map.! (Set.singleton x, Set.singleton y))
        set2
    )
    set1

conspiracy = Map.fromList
    [ ( (Set.singleton "Hera" , Set.singleton "Hera" )
      , Set.fromList [ "Hera", "Athene" ]
      )
    ...
    , ( (Set.singleton "Hera" , Set.singleton "Helene" )
      , Set.fromList [ "Athene", "Aphrodite", "Paris" ]
      )
    ...
    , ( (Set.singleton "Helene" , Set.singleton "Helene" )
      , Set.fromList [ "Hera" ]
      )
    ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Map creates a hashmap wich is O(1), but with a function you have to check each condition.

Edit: That is actually wrong. Map is a size-balanced binary tree, but that should give conspire a O(logn) complexity, while the function has to check every combination and thus has O(n) complexity.

Remember how patternmatching works:

```
f 0 = 0
f i = 1+f (i-1)
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```
f i = if i == 0
      then 0
      else 1+f (i-1)
```

You're esentially doing O(n) comparisons to find which function you want to execute.

With Map, it does a search in a binary tree, and only has to do O(logn) comparisons.

Comment: It’s actually syntactic sugar for a `case`, but it’s still linear.

Comment: Does this mean that using enumerated datatypes in Haskell in generally a bad idea? Since eventually you are going to write functions to manipulate them.

Comment: @André No, it means you should use both `Map` _and_ your enumerated type. Instead of `singleton "Hera"`, use `singleton Hera` -- it may be even faster, since it does no string comparison!

Comment: Thanks @Josh Lee for clarifying. I was going to write the C equivalent, but it didn't make sense in a Haskell question.

Comment: @nulvinge, If your claim of pattern match costing `O(N)` is true, then Map lookup would cost `O(N*log(N))` because `compare` can only be implemented with pattern matching, so your explanation is far from complete. Also, if anything, `if` is a syntactic sugar for pattern-matching, but not vice-versa.

Comment: To be precise, that's not `O(N*log(N))`, but `O(N*log(M))` with `N` being the number of distinct constructors and `M` being the size of the list.

Comment: Generally: C*logN<N, but this may not be true here, since C is pretty big. And it may be true that if is syntactic sugar for pattern-matching, pattern-matching didn't explain my point.

Comment: @nulvinge, If the keys in the `Map` have the same type as the thing being pattern-matched (`Eris`), as suggested by Daniel, we are comparing `C*log(N)` to `C` (not to `N`!) with `C` being the number of constructors of `Eris`. Obviously, `C` is the smaller complexity. If we, on the other hand, replace `Eris` with `String`, we get `C'*log(N)` versus `C'` where `C'` is the length of the string representation of `Eris`. Again `Map` loses, at least theoretically.

Comment: Why doesn't it have to try all N patterns to find the one that matches? And why can't Map simply compare them to give log(N) (a comparison is O(1))?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3535/discussion-between-rotsor-and-nulvinge)

Comment: I just would like to encourage anyone interested to read the discussion between Rotsor and nulvinge. Especially [this post](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1484840#1484840) seems to hint into the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Your first version runs slowly because of `List.nub` function, which is very inefficient. It works in `O(N^2)` time with `N` being the size of the list. Everything else will be dominated by `nub` for large `N`.

Comment: Originally i did not use List.nub but the following function definition: `composition [a] (b:bs) = List.union (composition [a] [b]) (composition [a] bs)` and `composition (a:as) ls = List.union (composition [a] ls) (composition as ls)` This was about as slow as the `List.nub` which i used to get roughly the same code in the first example as in the second.

Comment: I think the main point you make is that `nub` and `union` does not depend on the type to be orderable (instance of `Ord`), hence it can only do O(N^2). Whereas with any method that uses the restriction of orderable types (`Map`, `Set`, `sort`, etc.) can do it quicker.

Comment: I made the mistake to change my code for better readability before i posted it here. Originally i was using sets in the first example, too. I apologize for that. Since nulvinge addressed the problem i indicated in the heading i accept his answer. Thank you all.